# OpenLayers map whitescreens when I try to add icon functionality to it

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

For some reason my `OpenLayers` map completely **whitescreens** whenever I try to add support for showing icons on the map.
I've looked almost anywhere I can to no success; I also know that the page is loading/should be loading properly, as the HTML sidebar I've put there loads completely fine, however the map does not.

I'd appreciate any sort of feedback on this if possible, as I haven't been able to figure out getting icons on the map yet without this happening through multiple different solutions I've found/figured out.

I've attached the code below.

```
import "ol/ol.css";
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from "ol/layer";
import {defaults as defaultControls, FullScreen} from 'ol/control';
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import {Icon, Style} from 'ol/style';

const newportLonLat = [-71.307607, 41.529193];
const newportWebMercator = fromLonLat(newportLonLat)

var lat = 42;
var lng = -75;

var iconFeature = new Feature({
  geometry: new Point(ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
  name: 'The icon',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
});

var iconStyle = new Style({
  image: new Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png'
  }))
});

iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new Map({
  controls: defaultControls().extend([
    new FullScreen()
  ]),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new VectorLayer({
      style: function(feature) {
        return feature.get('style');
      },
      source: new VectorSource({features: [iconFeature]})
    })
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: newportWebMercator,
    zoom: 13
  })
});
```

Comment: You are using a mixture of modules and full build syntax.  Most of the full build syntax is in unused code but the `ol.proj.transform` is causing the problem.  It can be replaced by `fromLonLat` https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-nxw6l  Also if the feature has a style set it overrides the layer style so you do not need a style function .

Comment: Thank you so much @Mike!! This solution worked.  I'm pulling entries from a sql database using NodePG, and I think I understand how to go about plotting them for the map.  Would I need to adjust anything you sent to account for that besides changing the coordinates to lat, lon rather than static coordinates? Thank you again!